# How to know when a network computer is shut down

Tags: windows, crash, shutdown, logging

I have on my LAN a specialized computer running a program, and I need to know when (because I know it **is** happening) it shuts down.

<sup>By shutting down I don't mean a clean shutdown, I mean when the system crashes.</sup>

I was thinking that maybe I could have a task running every few minutes to ping that computer to see if it's still up, but ideally I want something (maybe there's a program out there that does this?) that will email me or at least write a log with some detailed information in it, e.g. CPU/HDD temperatures, S.M.A.R.T. Status, etc.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you just check the Event Log?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ping watchdog in a script, if the remote host responds to ICMP echo request.

If not, an arp ping will always work on the same subnet. Add a reasonable timeout and ping count to the command, and if it does timeout (several times), let your script alert you.

Otherwise, let it assume the remote host is up.